# Add object constraints and link to an object

Tags: python

I am hoping to get some help. This is the code I am using, but the constraint has no effect.

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') #deselect all object

bpy.data.objects['A'].select_set(True)
obj = bpy.context.window.scene.objects['A']
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
o = bpy.context.object

add_constraint = o.constraints.new('LIMIT_ROTATION')

target = bpy.data.objects['A']


bpy.context.object.constraints["Limit Rotation"].use_limit_z = True

bpy.context.object.constraints["Limit Rotation"].influence = 1
bpy.context.object.constraints["Limit Rotation"].min_z = 0.0872665
bpy.context.object.constraints["Limit Rotation"].max_z = 0.0872665

bpy.context.object.constraints["Limit Rotation"].owner_space = 'LOCAL'
```

Comment: *Well-intentioned tip*: Getting no help is most likely due to a bad question. From personal experience, I think the more effort you put into your question (research, your actual state, what you've tried, describing your actual goal, etc.), the quicker you'll get help and the better are the answers. Your questions mostly looking like "drive-by-questions", it's just a pile of code and little effort.

Answer (score 4):

**Some tidy up.**

In addition to [@Leanders answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/162291/15543) re limiting the constraint when using transform (which I've added in code below),  Note doesn't stop you setting  the z rotation property in UI to whatever..

If we wish to use context, would select those to add constraint to before script and then run from the context.  This is the fundamental concept of the context-operator paradigm. eg to run on object "A" select only "A" and run script below.

Test script. Adds constraint for all selected objects.  Note uses the reference to the newly created constraint `con`. It will have the default name only when there are no others with that name. Otherwise you add a new one and set the old one.

*I use `context = bpy.context` in test scripts, so they can be simply copied and pasted into operator or panel code later, where `context` is passed as an argument.*

Added code to remove other constraints of same type first.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context 

ob = context.object

for o in context.selected_objects:
    #o.constraints.clear() # removes all


    # remove other constraints by type
    lrcs = [c for c in o.constraints if c.type == 'LIMIT_ROTATION']
    while lrcs:
        o.constraints.remove(lrcs.pop())


    con = o.constraints.new( type='LIMIT_ROTATION')
    con.use_limit_z = True

    con.influence = 1
    con.min_z = 0.0872665
    con.max_z = 0.0872665

    con.owner_space = 'LOCAL'
    con.use_transform_limit = True
```

If you know the name of the target object is "A".  Unless you are going to later use operators on this object, there is no reason to set it as active and selected (context) to add modifiers to it this way.

```
scene = context.scene
o = scene.objects.get("A") #  if there is no object named A it will be None
if o:
    con = o.constraints.new(...) # as above.
```

For other constraints that need a target set, for example to add a constraint to each selected targeting context object

```
obs = context.selected_objects #safe to manipulate this prop
obs.remove(context.object)
for o in obs:
    con = o.constraint.new(...)
    con.object = context.object
```

Comment: The influence slider only works after I "Clear Parent" of the object, not using Python. The object wasn't parented.

Comment: Are you talking about a child of constraint?

Comment: The script adds the constraint perfectly, however the influence slider (object constraint panel) will have no effect, unless I select the object the click ALT P and "clear parent". This is confusing me a little because the object wasn't parented in the first place to any object.

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing your constraint by trying to transform the object, you have to enable the *For Transform* checkbox.

```
bpy.context.object.constraints["Limit Rotation"].use_transform_limit = True
```